# Using GetEnvironmentVariable method to move files

Tags: c#, winforms

I was using hard-coded directory path to Program Files to move file. I would now like to use the correct method to find the folder in Program Files.

I have found this method doing some Googling and it is what i would like to use:

```
static string ProgramFilesx86()
{
    if( 8 == IntPtr.Size || (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432"))))
    {
        return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramFiles(x86)");
    }

    return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramFiles");
}
```

I unfortunately am not sure how to implement and use this method.

1. Where do i insert the method in my app?
2. How do i use the above instead of this:

   ```
   if (File.Exists(@"C:\PROGRA~1\TEST\ok.txt"))
       File.Delete(@"C:\PROGRA~1\TEST\ok.txt");
   File.Copy(@"C:\PROGRA~1\PROGRAMFOLDER\ok.txt", @"C:\PROGRA~1\TEST\ok.txt");
   ```

Comment: Why deleting file, you may try File.Copy(srcFilename, destFilename, true) here true: specify overwrite allowed or not. True will overwrite file if it exist.

Comment: I thought that if they had User Account Control on that wouldnt work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's *much* easier to get the special folders like Program Files using

[Environment.SpecialFolders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx)

```
string programFilesFolder = 
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86)
```

Continuing that example you could do something like this

```
string pathToFile = 
    Path.Combine(programFilesFolder, @"TEST\ok.txt");

if (File.Exists(pathToFile)) 
    File.Delete(pathToFile);
```

**UPDATE**

Modified the code example to always get the 32-bit Program Files folder whether you're running 32- or 64-bit OS as @Mario pointed out that's what your original code was doing.

Comment: According to question code, user is trying to find x86 based ProgramFiles directory if its x64bit os. In Windows 64bit architecture it creates two directory, 1.ProgramFiles, 2.ProgramFiles (x86). Eric J. your code will return the only ProgramFile directory for x64 bit os, not ProgramFiles (x86).

Comment: How can you tell Environment.GetFolderPath() whether you need the 64bit or the 32 bit version? Does using ProgramFilesX86 work? The doc does not explicitley mention it

Comment: There's also Environment.SpecialFolders.ProgramFilesX86 if that's the case.  If it returns the same thing as ProgramFiles, it's a 32 bit machine.  You can certainly use it if you always want the 32-bit Program Files path, whether or not you're on a 32-bit or 64-bit machine.

Comment: If i am not wrong, i thought the first method posted also not only looks for 32 bit, but 64 bit as well as a 32bit using 64 bit? Thats why i wanted to use the first method i thought it is more secure

Comment: Ah you fixed it.  I'll remove my answer.

Comment: I consider the .NET preferred method "more secure" - in the sense that it's more likely to work in future Windows OS's - than a hack that checks environment variables :-)

Comment: And as I pointed out: You have to know where the program installs, not what the program folder is on the system!

Answer (score 0):

```
string fileName = Path.Combine( ProgramFilesx86(), applicationPath, @"ok.txt");

if (File.Exists( fileName ) )
{
   File.remove( fileName );
}

string sourceFile = Path.Combine( ProgramFilesx86(), @"\PROGRAMFOLDER", "ok.txt" );

File.Copy( sourceFile, fileName);
```

**Edit:**
You should not use this method. The program folder depends on the capability of the programs and not the system! You must know whether they install to the ProgramFiles or ProgramFilesX86 folder.
And then use Eric J.'s answer.

Comment: Oooh, Upvoted Erics post as the correct. can anyone use erics forumla in a example for a button?

Answer (score -1):

string sourceFolder = 
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles);
string source = 
    Path.Combine(sourceFolder, @"ok.txt");

string targetFolderPath =
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
string target = Path.Combine(targetFolderPath, @"ok.txt");

if (File.Exists(source))
    File.Delete(source);
File.Copy(targetFolderPath, source);

Comment: -1 copy of @Erics answer and wrong.. OP did not use MyDocuments

Comment: How can i use the method Eric found for a button please someone

Comment: By mydocuments i just wanted to show the power/reach of  Environment.SpecialFolder. It can definitely be program files

Comment: Bob : you can write this method on the button click, do you want me to give the code for button_click method?

Comment: yes please i am only new to C# and i see how it makes sence i am howvwer having trouble trying to make it workon a button click

Comment: Everybody is new at some point of time, need not to mention thatso here is the code. In the aspx page you have to make the button in the body tag like : <div>
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="click to delete"  OnClick="click"/>
    </div>   while on server side you have to make the code for the button like protected void click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    } and in between these curly brackets you may write the code you want to execute.

Comment: i have made buttons in the C# form app. I meant i don't know how to insert the string on a button_click

Comment: Unfortunately no, I already have buttons in the C# form app i have made, i need help using Erics forumla for a button_click....

Comment: You shouldnt need my project to help do a button_click example seeya.